# Server blacklisted from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, blacklist

Yesterday we installed a new plugin on our site to allow our posts to be posted to our Facebook page automatically. Well early morning Monday's and some testing code was left in that made the call a couple of thousand times in about an hour. Over 24 hours later, Facebook still returns:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#1) An error occured while creating the share","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

The post is going to {page_id}/feed and using the extended access_token, which doesn't expire for pages.

I know this is related to the IP of the server, as I can perform a post via curl on our other servers without and problems (just copy and pasting over the curl arguments). So I was wondering if anyone has experienced this before and if there is a policy to get your server removed from the blacklist, or is it just a wait it out type thing?

TIA!

Comment: I'm currently experiencing a similar situation. Although I'm getting a null response not that error message. I made a large number of calls to Facebook yesterday and I've tried my script on different servers and it worked. Did this issue resolve for you?